# Convert System.String to object

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell for querying Cisco switches for their interface status which is returned as a `System.String`. I want to convert this string into an object but am not sure how to go about this. If there was a way to break the string down by column width and carriage returns is the only way I can think of but I am not sure how to code that.

The string looks as follows:

```
Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Gi1/0/1   Port-Channel 1     connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 1000BaseLX SFP
Gi1/0/2   Port-Channel 1     connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 1000BaseLX SFP
Gi1/0/3   Port-Channel 28    connected    routed     a-full a-1000 1000BaseLX SFP
Gi1/0/4   Port-Channel 28    connected    routed     a-full a-1000 1000BaseLX SFP
```

Comment: Hi @Armando - I'm afraid your question is unclear. What code are you using the obtain the resultant string i.e. how are you querying the switches?

Comment: Try this cmdlet: [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable). As the table has a right aligned column (`Speed`) which are in fact not integers, you need ta add the `-Literal` switch. Example: `$YourString | ConvertFrom-SourceTable -Literal`